# Stream do different something with first and last item, Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this code, Can to do using tipically

```
private static final String FS = System.getProperty("file.separator");
JFileChooser folderChooser = new JFileChooser();
if (folderChooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
      String filename = folderChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
      String[] recursivePaths = filename.split(FS);
      TreePath treePath = null;
      for (String part : recursivePaths) {
        int row = (treePath == null ? 0 : treePaths.getRowForPath(treePath));
        treePath = treePaths.getNextMatch(part, row, Position.Bias.Forward);
        if (treePath == null) {

        }
      }
}
```

But I want to know if is it Possible using Java 8 Stream, aditionally

```
private static final String FS = System.getProperty("file.separator");
JFileChooser folderChooser = new JFileChooser();
if (folderChooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
      String filename = folderChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
      String[] recursivePaths = filename.split(FS);
      Stream.of(recursivePaths).forEach(partFile -> {
          // Do something with FIRST, But How Discover?
          // Do something with OTHERS
          // Do something with LAST, But How Discover?
      });
}
```

Comment: `Stream` is really not designed for this kind of thing.  You probably could hack it, but it introduces the potential for maintenance issues later.

Comment: Stream never ends...

Comment: In your loop, you are not identifying the last element either. So why do you want to do it with the Stream suddenly? Besides that, the entire operation using `getNextMatch` looks error prone. What if your tree contains `Foo` and `FooBar` beneath a node, but the user selected `FooBar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably better to handle first and last separately

```
private static final String FS = System.getProperty("file.separator");
JFileChooser folderChooser = new JFileChooser();
if (folderChooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    String filename = folderChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
    String[] recursivePaths = filename.split(FS);
    String first = recursivePaths[0];
    String last = recursivePaths[recursivePaths.length - 1];

    Arrays.stream(recursivePaths, 1, recursivePaths.length - 1).forEach( x -> {
       //stream the elements in the middle
    });
  });
}
```

Probably worth adding some check of the length for `recursivePaths`

Answer (score 0):

You can chop your sequence by going via a `List` then using `subList`.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but you may find `Stream.reduce` useful. You probably know that non-effectively finals from outside cannot be used in a lambda.

IMO, streams typically make code more difficult to understand, though they are very clever.